# add a column to csv file in python based on other columns

Tags: python, csv

I am using Python 3.6.2 and have the following csv file:

```
STATE,RATE,DEATHS
IA,4.2,166
NH,4.2,52
MA,4.3,309
CA,4.4,2169
CO,4.6,309
ID,4.6,106
NY,4.6,1087
VT,4.6,27
NJ,4.7,487
```

I am trying to add a new column to the file, where I multiply the rate column times the deaths column. The following table is what I'd like my results to look like.

```
STATE,RATE,DEATHS,NEW
IA,4.2,166,697.2
NH,4.2,52,218.2
MA,4.3,309,1328.7
CA,4.4,2169,9543.6
CO,4.6,309,1421.4
ID,4.6,106,487.6
NY,4.6,1087,5000.2
VT,4.6,27,124.2
NJ,4.7,487,2288.9
```

I've tried looking for an answer to this question but couldn't find anything similar to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't say if you have tried to do this in Python, but you've used a Python tag. So can we assume that you know how to use Python? There is an easy way to do this in Python with Pandas, but you'd have to know how to basically use Pandas with Python.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do in python but couldn't get anything close to what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a code writing service.  please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pandas library, this is fairly simple:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['NEW'] = df['RATE'] * df['DEATHS']
# You can save over the old file, though I would suggest saving a new one 
# in case you make a mistake
df.to_csv('new_filename.csv')
```

There are several cool things that the pandas library takes care of for us. First, we easily parse the csv using the `pd.read_csv()` statement. Next, pandas DataFrame objects (which is what the variable `df` is) allow us to use keys to access and create columns, much like a Python dictionary. When we perform mathematical operations using columns from the DataFrame, the pandas library actually performs the operation for each value in each column, so in our example, the index 0 in the 'RATE' column is multiplied by index 0 of the 'DEATHS' column.

In short, if you are going to access and manipulate spreadsheet-like files in python, pandas is a powerful and easy-to-use library.

Comment: I was working on my answer at the same time, and apparently you submitted it a little before I noticed you already had, so sorry I guess?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, I don't have the pandas module. Can you point me to a good source on how to install this module?

Comment: Do you have pip installed on your machine? If so, simply typing `pip install pandas` will work. If not, the installation documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks! I got it installed and the code to work. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/yourfile.csv')
df['NEW'] = df.RATE * df.DEATHS
df.to_csv('path/to/yournewfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('test.csv', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

# print new header
print(lines[0].strip() + ',NEWCOLUMN')

# loop through other lines starting from 1
for line in lines[1:]:
    line_items = line.strip().split(',')

    # your operation
    new_column = float(line_items[1]) * float(line_items[2])
    line_items.append(new_column)

    print(",".join(map(str, line_items)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv with `csv` built-in package and then manipulate with columns as you need. Of course, you can use `pandas` library, but like to use a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. Replace `StringIO` (just to make testing simple) in the example below with the file reading and the job is done.

```
from io import StringIO 
import csv

f_in = StringIO("""STATE,RATE,DEATHS
IA,4.2,166
NH,4.2,52
MA,4.3,309
CA,4.4,2169
CO,4.6,309
ID,4.6,106
NY,4.6,1087
VT,4.6,27
NJ,4.7,487""")

reader = csv.reader(f_in)

with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  headings = next(reader)
  headings.append('NEW')
  writer.writerow(headings)

  for row in reader:
    row.append(str(round(float(row[1]) * float(row[2]), 1)))
    writer.writerow(row)
```